# CfContent restricted to a folder

Tags: coldfusion

The application keeps the daily reports in a shared path. Our application generates the URL linking it to the excels like

```
http://application/ExcelTask/Index.cfm?type=Report&fileName=Report_Mar2014.xlsx
```

with the cfm code as

```
<cfif FileExists("#filePath#")> 
    <cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value="inline; filename=""#URL.fileName#"""> 
        <cfcontent type="application/vnd.ms-excel" file="#filePath#">
</cfif>
```

What we have found out if the users are aware of our directory structure the cfm files can be downloaded using the URL injection like

```
http://application/ExcelTask/Index.cfm?type=../ExcelTask&fileName=Index.cfm
```

I can add a condition to only allow files of type xls and xlsx only but that looks like a Plan B.

Any ideas how to restrict the folder access?

Comment: You should be validating that the `type` variable is only expected values (i.e. allowed folder names) and that filename never contains path traversal characters (i.e. consecutive dots or slashes).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use basic data sanitization skills to both clean and validate your `URL.type` and `URL.filename`.

- some replaceAll code to eliminate `../`, or
- try isValid("regex", some regex pattern...)

You can also validate against the session whether the current logged in user has the write to view/download the file for extra protection.

Comment: Thanks Henry. If folder restriction is not an option, I would use the data sanitation techniques instead. Thanks for confirming.